# Custom authentication provider in silex application

Tags: authentication, silex

I try to write custom authentication provider for LDAP-authentication using silex documentation - [Defining a custom Authentication Provider](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/security.html#defining-a-custom-authentication-provider).

But if I look into `$app['security.authentication_providers']` there are two providers. One that I defined `App\LdapAuthenticationProvider` and one  `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Provider\DaoAuthenticationProvider`

And when I try to authorize user I get error because there is call of a `App\LdapUserProvider::loadUserByUsername()` from class DaoAuthenticationProvider.

If I would have only one provider in `$app['security.authentication_providers']` I think I should not get error because my LDAP-provider do not call loadUserByUsername.

Here is dump of `$app['security.authentication_providers']`

```
array (size=2)
  0 => object(App\LdapAuthenticationProvider)[194]
    private 'userProvider' => 
      object(App\LdapUserProvider)[176]
        private 'ldap' => resource(57, ldap link)
        private 'defaultRoles' => 
          array (size=1)
          ...
    private 'providerKey' => string 'default' (length=7)
  1 => object(Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Provider\DaoAuthenticationProvider)[195]
    private 'encoderFactory' => 
      object(Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\EncoderFactory)[197]
        private 'encoders' => 
          array (size=1)
          ...
    private 'userProvider' => 
      object(App\LdapUserProvider)[176]
        private 'ldap' => resource(57, ldap link)
        private 'defaultRoles' => 
          array (size=1)
          ...
    private 'hideUserNotFoundExceptions' (Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Provider\UserAuthenticationProvider) => boolean true
    private 'userChecker' (Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Provider\UserAuthenticationProvider) => object(Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserChecker)[196]
    private 'providerKey' (Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Provider\UserAuthenticationProvider) => string 'default' (length=7)
```

So, does anybody know why there are extra provider and how can I get rid of it?

There are code for [bootstraping application](http://pastebin.com/4dcsnziH), [LdapAuthenticationListener](http://pastebin.com/JthKyCQU) and [LdapAuthenticationProvider](http://pastebin.com/LZuDWLQD).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is solved.

I've just extended my `LdapAuthenticationListener` class with symfony2 `UsernamePasswordFormAuthenticationListener` and change bootstarp like this:

```php
$app['security.authentication_listener.factory.ldap'] = $app->protect(
    function ($name, $options) use ($app) {
        $app['security.authentication_provider.'.$name.'.ldap'] = $app->share(
            function () use ($app) {
                return new LdapAuthenticationProvider(
                    $app['security.user_provider.default'],
                    'ldap'
                );
            }
        );

        $app['security.authentication_listener.'.$name.'.ldap'] = $app->share(
            function () use ($app, $name, $options) {
                $app['security.authentication.success_handler.'.$name] =
                    $app['security.authentication.success_handler._proto']($name, $options);
                $app['security.authentication.failure_handler.'.$name] =
                    $app['security.authentication.failure_handler._proto']($name, $options);

                return new LdapAuthenticationListener(
                    $app['security'],
                    $app['security.authentication_manager'],
                    $app['security.session_strategy'],
                    $app['security.http_utils'],
                    $name,
                    $app['security.authentication.success_handler.'.$name],
                    $app['security.authentication.failure_handler.'.$name],
                    array_merge(
                        array(
                            'check_path' => '/admin/login_check',
                            'login_path' => '/login',
                        ),
                        $options
                    ),
                    $app['logger'],
                    $app['dispatcher'],
                    null
                );
            }
        );

        return array(
            'security.authentication_provider.'.$name.'.ldap',
            'security.authentication_listener.'.$name.'.ldap',
            null,
            'pre_auth'
        );
    }
```

I need custom authentication listener to overwrite token in authentication method and authentication provider retrieve user from user provider by username and password `$this->userProvider->loadUserByUsernameAndPassword($usernam, $password)`

Comment: However, still can't get why ``$app['security.authentication_providers']`` has two providers.

Comment: Unfortunately I can not. This project is withdrawn now and I have not access to it.
But the main idea was to write correct LdapAuthenticationListener that I archived by extending it from UsernamePasswordFormAuthenticationListener. And there is a code in a bootstrap to register new factory to handle ldap-authentication. Also take a look at code at pastebin, linku could be found in the very first comment. I think I did not change code in these classes too much.