# How do I implement a LDAP with Silex

Tags: symfony, ldap, silex

As the title indicates, I don't even know where to begin on this one. There isn't much documentation about this for Silex. Symfony has a implementation of this but only for the 2.8-3.0dev environment.

I found these 2 links which are helpful but didn't really answer my question.

https://github.com/warmans/silex-ldap-auth-controller-provider (litek/silex-php-engine seems to be obsolete)

https://github.com/DerManoMann/ldap-auth-service-provider (needs to use silex 2.0dev)

Notes:

- Currently using Silex 1.3 / Symfony 2.7
- I have my LdapUserProvider (UserProviderInterface) all ready.
- I didn't need modify UserAdvancedInterface.
- I want to use Zend/ldap

Any guidance or example will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you wrap https://github.com/zendframework/zend-ldap in a custom service provider?

Comment: That's honestly the route I wanted to take but I seem to lack the experience / knowledge to do so.

Comment: If you're using Symfony, you can use [this](https://packagist.org/packages/imag/ldap-bundle) bundle which has it all already implemented for you. If you want a library to only bind to ldap, you can use zend/ldap, raw php ldap or [tiesa/ldap](https://packagist.org/packages/tiesa/ldap)

Comment: [Symfony Ldap Component](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/tree/2.8/src/Symfony/Component/Ldap) is out there for the 2.8 and [Silex is compatible up to <3.0](https://github.com/silexphp/Silex/blob/1.3/composer.json#L26) so you could use that to begin your own provider (which won't be easy).

Comment: Some links you may want to check: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C1y6fxetP5k https://speakerdeck.com/rouffj/mastering-the-security-components-authentication-mechanism https://github.com/rouffj/HowtoSecurityBundle

Comment: In the 2.8 Symfony also introduced [Guard](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/tree/2.8/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Guard) theoretically an [easy way to extend the security component](https://knpuniversity.com/blog/guard-authentication). Keep in mind that AFAIK this is new territory so you'll have to be brave :-)

Comment: I haven't had any luck so far with most of these but http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16710529/custom-authentication-provider-in-silex-application has been my best guide but it isn't complete.